# How can I increase the AC voltage from a function generator?

Tags: function-generator

I'm doing an assignment where the objective is building a function generator. We used [AD9850](http://www.analog.com/en/products/clock-and-timing/direct-digital-synthesis/ad9850.html) to generate a wave but its output voltage is below the requirement. (We require 10 Vpp, but mine is about 1 Vpp).

My colleague is thinking of using op-amp to increase its voltage.

I'm looking for other alternative solutions for this problem.

Comment: Could you post a schematic of what you have done so far, as well as any ideas you have considered?

Comment: But do you want to buy a chip or build your own analog circuit?

Comment: Just noted this on the datasheet: "Both versions of the AD9850 evaluation board[s] are designed to interface to the parallel printer port of a PC." Well, those days are well and long gone. Probably can't sell those boards anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a 1:10 signal transformer such as a microphone transformer.

You have omitted any waveform, load impedance and frequency specifications from your question so it is not possible to say if this is an acceptable solution to your problem. Note that a transformer will work best over a range of frequencies but will attenuate outside that range.

Answer (score 0):

Use an LM7171 amplifier from TI. It has a bandwidth of 200 MHz and can operate from +/- 15V supplies. This will give the voltage swing you need. It also has up to 100 mA output current. Check out the datasheet at TI.